# Which is kernel similar gaussian kernel?

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, image-processing, gaussian-elimination

I must find a kernel that statisfies as follows:
[image]

In the my reference paper, the author suggest gaussian kernel that is
[image]

The purpose of that kernel is that it will take a weight for each points around center point (mean value), ànd that weighted value decreases drastically to zero as points go away from center point

The gaussian kernel is very good to approximate that properties. But selectec the kernel size is very challenge task. Could you suggest to me the other kernel that can satisfy above properties
And I have a ball kernel that defined
[image]

Which is different between ball kernel and gaussian kernel? It is similar the average kernel,right?

Comment: Switching to a different smoothing filter will not help you select the kernel size. I am not sure you are asking the right question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any decreasing function of the norm such that the integral in (3) converges, and use the value of the integral as a normalization factor.

The simplest is the box function, $f(||u||)=1$ for $||u||\le\sigma$ and $0$ elsewhere. The normalization factor will be the volume of the hypersphere $\frac{\pi^{n/2}\sigma^n}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}$.

If you convolve this kernel with itself several times, you will obtain smoother and smoother [kernels](http://nghiaho.com/?attachment_id=1189) of finite support, that still fulfill the requirements.

As a goodie, these kernels are separable, just like the Gaussian.

UPDATE:

Caution: the box filter is separable only in the case of a cube, not a sphere.

Comment: The box filter does decrease drastically to zero. In fact it is exactly zero as soon as $||u||>\sigma$ (can't be more drastic) and fully complies with the three requirements. The auto-convolutions of the box filter do the same, in a smoother way.

Comment: Thank you sir, do you know which is benefit of box kernel. I think box kernel is good approximation of gaussian kernel. I read in your referene. But it does not mention it. Maybe it independent with kernel size, right?

Comment: The box kernel is very simple to compute, and also extremely fast: it can be implemented so that the number of operations per pixel does not depend on the value of sigma.

Comment: Thank you so much. The $\sigma$ in the gaussian and the radius $\sigma$ in box kernel is same meaning, right? But i think the radius values is bigger than gaussian kernel size, For example, with same image, radius values is about 11, while $\sigma$ in gausian is 3. But the purpose of two term are weighted points based on distance with center point. Is it correct?

Comment: "the radius values is bigger than gaussian kernel size": these are values that you choose freely.

Comment: I check box kernel and ran it. It is look like ball kernel, right? Or difference. The ball kernel is defined at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060844/truncated-gaussian-kernel-implementation-matlab-right?noredirect=1#comment38993492_25060844

Comment: This link does not define a ball kernel, just a standard Gaussian. The box has constant weight.

Comment: Ok. I updated my question. Please see the defination again

Comment: Can't understand your question. You ask "What is the difference between A and B ? Is it the same as C ?" Please disambiguate.

Comment: Which is C. Let see that B is ball kernel and K is gaussian kernel. Which is different between B and K?

Comment: C is the average kernel, as you wrote. The box has constant weight.

Comment: Sorry, i mistaken it. Average kernel is similar box kernel that your link. So, Do you think which best kernel for image filter. I think gaussian is best because it consider spatial weighted factor in its neighbor pixels, while Ball and Box kernels is same.

Comment: "Best" is meaningless if you don't define your comparison criteria.

Comment: My comparison criteria is image filter. I think compare betwen gaussian kernel and box kernel, they are same result (as your link). Comparison between ball kernel and gaussian kernel, I think gaussian kernel is better than ball kernel for image denoising but the image detail will lost when size of kernel is large. Is it correct?

Comment: All these kernels have the same effect: they reduce noise and erase detail; the effect is stronger for larger sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard symmetric mollification kernel. Such a function is compactly supported but this is in agreement with your conditions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier

More precisely: Take

$$
\varphi: x\mapsto C \exp\left(-\frac{1}{1 - x^2}\right)
$$
($x\in (-1,1)$ and $\varphi=0$ else) where $C$ is chosen such that
$$
\frac{1}{C}=\int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{1 - x^2}\right)\mathrm dx.
$$

EDIT: Observe that every function $f_\lambda (x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\varphi\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)$ for $\lambda >0$ has the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you sir, $f_{\lambda}(x)$ is modified kernel, right? And $\lambda$ is kernel size,right?

Comment: Exactly. The support of $f_\lambda$ has measure $2\lambda$ and the maximal "height" of $f_\lambda$ is given by $\frac{C}{\lambda \mathrm e}$. As $\lambda\to 0$, you'll get a Dirac sequence.